# Correct way to switch window manager (to Openbox) in Debian stretch MATE

Tags: debian, window-manager, mate-desktop

After switching to modesetdriver for:

```
lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor      Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [17aa:21f3]
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I had tearing when I watched videos. I was searching and read this could be a problem with the compositor. In my case it turns out it was the problem, so I tried to replace Marco with Openbox + Compton.
In mate-tweak Openbox is not offered.

```
mate-tweak
Window Manager is: Unknown
Base layout: fedora
Current layout: fedora
```

[image: mate-tweak]

I tried switching the window manager to Openbox using update-alternatives.

```
readlink -f /etc/alternatives/x-window-manager
/usr/bin/openbox
```

The next try was to use gsettings.

```
gsettings list-recursively org.mate.session.required-components
org.mate.session.required-components dock ''
org.mate.session.required-components windowmanager 'openbox'
org.mate.session.required-components panel 'cairo-dock' 
org.mate.session.required-components filemanager 'caja'
```

At least I'm ending up with starting Openbox and Compton in autostart from mate-session, but I'm afraid this is not a smart solution. How can I make it better?

Note: Creating an intel.conf is not an option. This pushes me right to vt, and lightdm refuses to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short and painless. I moved the desktop files for openbox and and compton from

```
$HOME/.config/autostart/
```

to

```
/etc/xdg/autostart
```

and removed

```
apt purge mate-tweak
```